# Artifactory OSS Repository Browser throws stacktrace with NullPointerException

Tags: javascript, java, artifactory

Running jFrog artifactory OSS v5.4.6 on Amazon Linux.
Periodically receive infinite spinner when using Artifact Repository Browser in admin GUI while viewing remote maven repos.

System log shows stacktrace:

```
2017-09-21 12:31:17,884 [http-nio-8081-exec-11] [ERROR] (o.a.r.c.e.GlobalExceptionMapper:48) - null
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.artifactory.ui.rest.model.artifacts.browse.treebrowser.nodes.JunctionNode.getRepoPkgType(JunctionNode.java:95) ~[artifactory-rest-ui-5.4.6.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.ui.rest.model.artifacts.browse.treebrowser.nodes.JunctionNode.fetchItemTypeData(JunctionNode.java:87) ~[artifactory-rest-ui-5.4.6.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.ui.rest.service.artifacts.browse.treebrowser.tree.BrowseTreeNodesService.execute(BrowseTreeNodesService.java:41) ~[artifactory-rest-ui-5.4.6.jar:na]
    at ...
```

code:

`function() {
    var t = 0,
        e = function(t, e) {
            return "function" != typeof t || t.replaced ? t : (e.replaced = !0, e)
        };
    if ("undefined" != typeof CustomEvent && "function" == typeof window.dispatchEvent) {
        var n = function(e) {
                try {
                    if ("object" == typeof e && (e = JSON.stringify(e)), "string" == typeof e) return window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("lprequeststart", {
                        detail: {
                            data: e,
                            requestID: ++t
                        }
                    })), t
                } catch (t) {}
            },
            o = function(t) {
                try {
                    window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("lprequestend", {
                        detail: t
                    }))
                } catch (t) {}
            };
        "undefined" != typeof XMLHttpRequest && XMLHttpRequest.prototype && XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send && (XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = e(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send, function(t) {
            return function(e) {
                var u = this,
                    r = n(e);
                return r && u.addEventListener("loadend", function() {
                    o({
                        requestID: r,
                        statusCode: u.status
                    })
                }), t.apply(u, arguments)
            }
        }(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send))), "function" == typeof fetch && (fetch = e(fetch, function(t) {
            return function(e, u) {
                var r = n(u),
                    c = t.apply(this, arguments);
                if (r) {
                    var i = function(t) {
                        o({
                            requestID: r,
                            statusCode: t && t.status
                        })
                    };
                    c.then(i).catch(i)
                }
                return c
            }
        }(fetch)));
        var u = function(t) {
                return e(t, function() {
                    try {
                        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("lpsubmit"))
                    } catch (t) {}
                    return t.apply(this, arguments)
                })
            },
            r = function() {
                if (document && document.forms && document.forms.length > 0)
                    for (var t = 0; t < document.forms.length; ++t) document.forms[t].submit = u(document.forms[t].submit)
            };
        document && "interactive" === document.readyState || "complete" === document.readyState ? r() : window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", r, !0), document.createElement = e(document.createElement, function(t) {
            return function() {
                var e = t.apply(this, arguments);
                return e && "FORM" === e.nodeName && e.submit && (e.submit = u(e.submit)), e
            }
        }(document.createElement))
    }
}();`

Comment: try also adding the code that is causing the problem, to give a better idea on how to help you

Comment: Yes your right.....cleaned up my pasted code too much.....

http://artifactory.url.com/artifactory/ui/treebrowser?compacted=true&$no_spinner=true

triggered:
500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: i edited a bit your question to un-minify the code, otherwise un-readable. You should narrow the code to the lines that are causing the exception. Actually i can see a java exception in your log, but you pasted your js function. Sure that it is the right code? Anyway i invite you to carefully ready this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask in order to provide clearer and more answarable questions.

Comment: The posted stacktrace indicates it is a backend issue, so the JavaScript code is less relevant. Can you post the full Java stacktrace?